# Cloud functions Circle Image Imagemagick

Tags: firebase, imagemagick, google-cloud-functions

I would like to convert uploaded pictures to Firebase Storage into circled images using Cloud functions and resize them.
Having a look at the documentation of ImageMagick I am wondering about the syntax to use for this task. Using the below to resize the image which works like a charm. But how would I add the commands into this and which ones to use best?

```
return spawn('convert', [tmpFilePath, '-resize', '250x250', tmpFilePath]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what a 'circle image' means, but perhaps applying [Vignette](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/transform/#vignette) effect?

```
convert -size 250x250 plasma: -background white -vignette 0x0 output.png
```

[image: output.png]

So your command may be...

```
return spawn('convert', [
    tmpFilePath,
    '-resize', '250x250',
    '-background', 'white',
    '-vignette', '0x0',
    tmpFilePath
]);
```

Comment: Sorry I meant circular image....too hot this summer. Thanks for sharing this. Have changed background from white to transparent. This goes into the right direction. However I would like to create kind of profile images for users. And using vignette would not work as it cuts away too much.

Comment: Most user-profile images you see on the web are not "circular images", but unedited images displayed as circular by leveraging CSS3. Can you post an example image if what your attempting? Fred's examples are detailed, and can be modified to fit any complex shape.

Comment: @emcconville is there any way to send the manipulated output directly to response when using express in cloud function, I mean not saving it to any temp path.

Answer (score 2):

`emcconville` probably has the simplest method. You may just need to make the background transparent and replace the plasma image with a real image.

If you want the outside to be transparent, be sure to save your output to PNG or TIFF and not JPG. JPG does not support transparency.

Input:

[image]

```
convert lena.jpg -background none -vignette 0x0 output.png
```

[image]

However, the circle's perimeter will not extend to the edges of the image.

To make it do that, you have to change the arguments as follows:

```
convert lena.jpg -background none -vignette 0x0+0+0 output2.png
```

[image]

But here is another method that is a bit longer and more complex (assuming you have a square image).

If by "circled images" you mean make the outside of a circle the size of the image transparent, you can do that in ImageMagick command line as follows:

```
1) Read the image (and somehow get its size)
2) Then create a new image the same size and fill with black and draw a white circle supplying the center point and any point on the perimeter
3) Put the circle image into the alpha channel of the original
```

Original:

[image]

Unix Syntax. (For Windows remove the \s in the following)

```
convert lena.jpg \( -size 256x256 xc:black -fill white -draw "circle 128,128 128,255" \) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite result.png
```

[image]

In Unix syntax one can get the dimensions of the input image as follows:

```
WxH=`convert -ping lena.jpg -format "%wx%h" info:`
ww=`echo $WxH | cut -dx -f1`
hh=`echo $WxH | cut -dx -f2`
ww2=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$ww/2]" info:`
hh2=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$hh/2]" info:`
hhm1=$((hh-1))
convert lena.jpg \( -size ${ww}x${hh} xc:black -fill white -draw "circle $ww2,$hh2 $ww2,$hhm1" \) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite result2.png
```

[image]

If you do not have a square image, then you must use the minimum dimension of the input image as the circle diameter. This also works for a square image.

Input:

[image]

```
dim=`convert -ping monet2.jpg -format "%[fx:min(w,h)]" info:`
dim2=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$dim/2]" info:`
dimm1=$((dim-1))
convert monet2.jpg \( -size ${dim}x${dim} xc:black -fill white -draw "circle $dim2,$dim2 $dim2,$dimm1" \) -alpha off -gravity center -compose copy_opacity -composite result4.png
```

[image]

If we use the vignette method on a non-square image, then you will get an elliptical region.

```
convert monet2.jpg -background none -vignette 0x0+0+0 output3.png
```

[image]

Comment: You totally understand what I am trying to achieve. But I am wondering how to put the syntax and code you provided in the format I can use in Cloud Functions. A format like mentioned above: return spawn('convert', [
    tmpFilePath,
    '-resize', '250x250',
    '-background', 'white',
    '-vignette', '0x0',
    tmpFilePath
]); I tried to get it into Cloud functions but Imagemagick runs into an error and stops.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know Cloud functions.

Comment: Have you tried `emcconville's` code below and change the background color to none with vignette arguments of 0x0+0+0?

Comment: Have tried emcconville's code but will also try the adaption you have recommened. Also will try to figure out the required syntax for Cloud functions in regards of the code you provided.

Comment: I would suggest you first experiment to see if you can simply convert one file to another format. That way, you can determine if the issue is with ImageMagick installation or Cloud syntax. There should be simple examples for using ImageMagick in Cloud format. Once you can ensure you can do that successfully, then add in the vignette command. Here is one tutorial -- https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/imagemagick and another at https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples